# Java(Spring)のエラー

Tags: java, spring

以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
メソッド getUploadFile() は型 KnpnkkKnskForm で未定義です。
メソッド setOutputFileNm(String) は型 KnpnkkKnskForm で未定義です。
```

この場合はKnpnkkKnskFormに定義しないといけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

この場合は恐らく誰かのコードを使ってビルドしているでしょうか、
もし誰かのコードを使ってビルドするならばインポート先を探してインポートした方がいいです。